# Creating a pseudo email database

Tags: database-design

I am creating a database for Job offers website between Employer and Applicants that required sending Email between the two in MSSQL. Let's say I have 3 tables like these:

```
Employer
ID int idetity(1,1),
Name nvarchar(50),
Email nvarchar(50)

Applicants
ID int identity(1,1),
Name nvarchar(50),
Email nvarchar(50)

Mail
MailID int identity(1,1),
Sender nvarchar(50),
Receiver nvarchar(50),
Title nvarchar(100),
Content nvarchar(1000),
Status nvarchar(50)
```

In Mail table, the Status indicate whether the Mail is sent, unread, read, or delete. Is this the right way to do this? Should I link the Mail table with Employer and Applicant? If so, should I link what with what? Since I want to get the sent Mail of Employer and Applicant, check whether mail is Read,Unread or deleted.

Any help is appreciate

Answer (score 0):

I would create "Status" as a lookup table

```
SentStatus 
StatusId smallint identity (1,1)
StatusLabel char (10)
```

As it is easier to maintain and also add values to.

Of course, you should link "mail" to "Employer" and "Applicant" table using a many-to-many relationship.

Be mindful of over-using "var" if you don't need it, and definitely of the difference between nchar and char: if you know in advance that "status" is going to be a label in English which you assign, you don't need to accommodate for "nchar" which is double in length.